# Bubble Chart in iOS application

Tags: iphone, ios, graph, core-plot, bubble-chart

I need to implement bubble chart in an iPad application with each bubble having user interaction (touch event) to navigate to a detailed view.

Is there any framework or a way to do so (like bargraph, piechart, linegraph using coreplot)??

I tried implementing manually even using CGContextRef for each bubble as below

```
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIColor *grayColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.5];
[grayColor set];
CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(xaxis+2,yaxis+2,size-4,size-4);
CGContextSetLineWidth(c,4);
CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(c, rectangle);
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(c, rectangle);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, [bubbleColor CGColor]);
CGContextFillPath(c);
```

but unable to crop the edges from having user interaction i.e, touch event (since these bubbles are circles inscribed in UIView's).

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use a scatter plot for this. Implement the `-symbolForScatterPlot:recordIndex:` datasource method to provide a custom plot symbol for each plot point. Vary the size, shape, fill, etc., of the symbols as desired based on the data.

Comment: Hi Eric,

Thanks for your support.
But even -symbolForScatterPlot:recordIndex: is unable to recogize the edges. I mean the same issue is repeating there aswell.

Comment: The `plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection` controls the hit tolerance. Unfortunately, the same value applies to the whole plot so you can't use a small value for small bubbles and a larger value for large bubbles.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/aurosetteview) and [this](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/dbtilebutton). Also, you could try [`OBShapedButton`](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton) with your images. Hope this helps :)